# what HD cameras should be used and for what purpose?

Tags: recommendations, camera, video-recording

I was looking for a camera the other day and I came across a few options. GoPro Session 5, Caddx Orca, Gopro Hero 8 Black, Insta360 One R, and the GoPro Hero 7 silver. I realize that these are all good cameras and I was wondering how to choose the right one. Are there certain ones better for certain scenarios? Should I choose based on durability? Should I choose the cheapest option? What are the best ways to choose an HD camera for a quadcopter?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drones SE! This is a good question, but a bit too general. Can you please add some context to your question about what you were expecting to do with the camera? That would enable people to post answers that will better fit what you had in mind.

Comment: The problem with this question is that the 'best' camera is going to change every few months.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about all the cameras, but here is my opinion.

If you want the best video quality you can get today and not be too heavy for a 5" FPV drone, then you want the GoPro Hero 8.  That will obviously change quickly if something better comes along.  The Hero 8 also has great stability with Hypersmooth or you can opt to use ReelSteady Go with it.  Downsides are the size, weight, form factor, and cost.

The benefit of the GoPro Hero 7 is that it is slightly lighter than the 8, has a removable lens, accepts ND filters better, and Hypersmooth is still quite good.  However, it does not work as well with ReelSteady Go.

The GoPro Session 5 was the go-to camera for FPV drones for years and lots of people still use it because of its size, weight, and form factor.  However, GoPro does not make them anymore so they are not as easy to get.

If you want stabilized HD footage for a drone that can't carry a GoPro, then consider using the Insta360 Go.  They are tiny, lightweight, and can thus be used on very small drones.

If you are not looking for the best quality, and the cost is more important, then consider some of the cheaper options like the Caddx camera.

I'd say the best way to choose a camera all depends on what your needs are, what you want out of it etc.  If you just want decent videos for Instagram, you will have a different answer than someone shooting cinematic footage for commercial use.

And one final bit, be sure to get some sort of protection plan on the camera because you will most likely kill it at some point.  If you can buy the camera from Best Buy, they offer a great Geek Squad protection plan.  Another option for the GoPro cameras is the GoPro plan.

Comment: I would recommend the Runcam 5 Orange as a very good Session 5 alternative which is still produced and widely available. It has the same form factor and is relatively light. But be aware that the Session 5 was waterproof, the Orange isn't.